# Import s3 bucket from one stack to other stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have created S3 Bucket with deletepolicy retain using cloud formation, I Have exported the created bucket using Export in outputs in cloudformation.
Now I want to use the same s3 bucket in another stack using import

Cloud formation for s3:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Creates an S3 bucket to be used for static content/website hosting.",
    "Parameters": {

        "AssetInsightId": {
            "Description": "Asset Insight ID",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "206153"
        },
        "ResourceOwner": {
            "Description": "tr:resource-owner",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "####"
        },
        "EnvironmentType": {
            "Description": "tr:environment-type",

            "Default": "preprod",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": ["preprod", "prod"],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must specify preprod, prod."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties": {

                "BucketName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "a${AssetInsightId}-s3bucket-${EnvironmentType}"
                },
                "Tags": [{

                        "Key": "tr:application-asset-insight-id",
                        "Value": {
                            "Fn::Sub": "${AssetInsightId}"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "Key": "tr:environment-type",
                        "Value": {
                            "Fn::Sub": "${EnvironmentType}"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {

        "S3Bucket": {
            "Description": "Information about the value",
            "Description": "Name of the S3 Resource Bucket",
            "Value": "!Ref S3Bucket",
            "Export": {
                "Name": "ExportS3Bucket"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

cloud formation to use created s3 bucket from another template with import 
Second template :

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Creates an S3 apigateway to be used for static content/website hosting.",
    "Parameters": {

        "AssetInsightId": {
            "Description": "Asset Insight ID",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "206153"
        },
        "ResourceOwner": {
            "Description": "tr:resource-owner",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "swathi.koochi@thomsonreuters.com"
        },
        "EnvironmentType": {
            "Description": "tr:environment-type",

            "Default": "preprod",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": ["preprod", "prod"],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must specify preprod, prod."
        },
        "endpointConfiguration": {
            "Description": "tr:endpoint-configuration",

            "Default": "REGIONAL",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": ["REGIONAL", "EDGE"],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must specify REGIONAL, EDGE."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {

     "S3BucketImport": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",

            "Properties": {

                "BucketName": {"Fn::ImportValue" :  "ExportS3Bucket"}

            }
        },












        "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "MyAPI",
                "Description": "API Gateway rest api with cloud formation",
                "EndpointConfiguration": {
                    "Types": [{
                            "Ref": "endpointConfiguration"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "APIGateWayResource": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
            "Properties": {
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi"
                },
                "ParentId": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi", "RootResourceId"]
                },
                "PathPart": "test"
            }

        },
        "APIGatewayPostMethod": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
            "Properties": {
                "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
                "HttpMethod": "POST",

                "Integration": {
                    "Type": "AWS_PROXY",
                    "IntegrationHttpMethod": "POST",
                    "Uri": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:861756181523:function:GreetingLambda/invocations"
                    }

                },
                "MethodResponses": [{
                        "ResponseModels": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "Ref": "PostMethodResponse"
                            }
                        },
                        "StatusCode": 200
                    }
                ],

                "ResourceId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayResource"
                },

                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi"
                }
            }
        },
        "PostMethodResponse": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
            "Properties": {
                "ContentType": "application/json",
                "Name": "PostMethodResponse",
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi"
                },
                "Schema": {
                    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                    "title": "PostMethodResponse",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Email": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        "RestApiDeployment": {
            "DependsOn": "APIGatewayPostMethod",
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
            "Properties": {
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi"
                }
            }
        },

        "RestAPIStage": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Properties": {
                "DeploymentId": {
                    "Ref": "RestApiDeployment"
                },
                "MethodSettings": [{
                        "DataTraceEnabled": true,
                        "HttpMethod": "*",

                        "ResourcePath": "/*"
                    }
                ],
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateWayRestResourceRestApi"
                },
                "StageName": "Latest"
            }

        },
        "APIGateWayDomainName": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName",
            "Properties": {
                "CertificateArn": {
                    "Ref": "myCertificate"
                },
                "DomainName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [".", [{
                                "Ref": "AssetInsightId"
                            }, {
                                "Ref": "EnvironmentType"
                            }, "api"]]

                },
                "EndpointConfiguration": {
                    "Types": [{
                            "Ref": "endpointConfiguration"
                        }
                    ]
                }

            }
        },
        "myCertificate": {
            "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
                "DomainName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [".", [{
                                "Ref": "AssetInsightId"
                            }, {
                                "Ref": "EnvironmentType"
                            }, "api"]]

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when I/m trying to import using Import Value, I'm getting error saying

> S3BucketImport 
>   CREATE_FAILED   Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 9387EBE0E472E559; S3 Extended Request ID: o8EbE20IOoUgEMwXc7xVjuoyQT03L/nnQ7AsC94Ff1S/PkE100Imeyclf1BxYeM0avuYjDWILxA=)

Comment: In your 2nd template, you have a resource named S3BucketImport with the imported S3 bucket name. That bucket, presumably, already exists from the first template. Just reference it in the second stack, don't try to re-create it. Also, when exporting the bucket use `{ "Ref" : "S3Bucket" }` instead of `"!Ref S3Bucket"`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarmod correctly pointed out,

In your first template, export the s3 bucket name using `{ "Ref" : ",S3Bucket" }`

In your second template, you don't have to create the bucket again.you can use the exported value from the first template if you want to refer the bucket name from resources. But i don't see any of the resources in the second template refer the S3 bucket name.

Comment: IM creating stack in same region.

Comment: Do not use `AWS::S3::Bucket` in the 2nd template. Instead, use [`Fn::ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html).

Comment: @Swathi could you please tell us where are you going to use "BucketName" resource in your second template. I can see in your second template you are only importing it from 1st template and not using anywhere in your second template.